# Set a BitSet as a primitive type?

Tags: java, object, primitive-types, bitset

In Java, can you create a BitSet of size 8 and store it as a byte in order to output it?  The documentation on BitSets doesn't mention it.  Does that mean no?

Comment: seems like pretty obvious functionality, dunno why it wasn't included in the jdk.

Comment: You can never cast an Object to a primitive as a primitive is not an Object.

Comment: @Steve Kuo - he didn't ask for casting.  you could have something like BitSet.asByte() which returns a byte containing the first 8 bits.  (and for that matter, auto-unboxing _does_ allow you to cast certain objects to primitives).

Comment: It did mention casting before it was edited. I was going to say that autoboxing is not the same as casting, but I guess it could be considered so, since casting is just a term for type conversion. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cast_(computer_science)

Comment: @Steve Kuo - heh, well, it didn't say "casting" when i was writing that last comment. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast `BitSet` to `byte`.

You can write code to do what you want though. Given a `BitSet` named `bits`, here you go:

```
byte output = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (bits.get(i)) {
        output |= 1 << (7 - i);
    }
}
```

**Update**: The above code assumes that your bits are indexed 0 to 7 from left to right. E.g. assuming the bits `01101001` you consider bit 0 to be the leftmost 0. If however you're assigning the bits from right to left then bit 0 would be the rightmost 1. In which case you want `output |= 1 << i` instead.

Comment: can you explain this line  output |= 1 << (7 - i);

Comment: @Trevor it's clearly an unhappy guy getting attacked by a Guillotine. :-) Nah, `|=` means "or equals", or `output = output | 1 << (7 - i)`. Now that `1 << (7 - 1)` part means take a 1 and shift it over. So you're essentially saying "Set the ith bit on `output` to 1."

Comment: The `|=` takes the last `output` and performs bitwise `OR` on it and `1 << (7 - i)`. Essentially it's manually setting the bits for the `output` byte.

Comment: @glowcoder i liked the guillotine version better! Thanks, this really helps.  To clarify, if output = 1 = 00000001, then after that line of code output would = 2 = 00000010 ?

Comment: If you did both 1 and 2, you'd have 00000011.

Comment: @glowcoder What if I want to prepare this so I can read it back into a BitSet?  Would I use >> instead?

Comment: Yes, and mask it with `& 0x1`.

Comment: @Trevor `&` is the and operator. If you had 0101 and 0110, `a&b=0100`. It takes the and of each individual bit. `0x1` is just `1`. You could probably just use `1`. I am used to use `0x` to say to whoever reads it "I mean the bits, not the number!" even if they're they same. We can use 1. If you have 1, it's represented as `00000001`. Now, anything `& 0` is 0. So the result of `x & 1` will be 0 if the last digit is 0, and 1 if the last digit is 1. So, you use `>>` to shift down so the first bit is the bit you're after, and `& 1` to see if that bit is set to 1 or not.

Comment: @glowcode ONE more question, i promise.  is this the write snippet to feed in a 1 from the left:  bit |= 1 >>> (bitindex)

Comment: @WhiteFang34 the update was very helpful, but I also need to shift to the left after that operation to prepare for the next incoming bit.  i tried output << 1; but that doesnt seem to compile.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in for that. You could implement that yourself obviously.

Answer (score 0):

bit set is an array of bits

the JVM uses a 32-bit stack cell ie each register in the JVM stores one 32-bit address

we know that primitive boolean is set to be 1 bit but handled as 32 bit. array of boolean will be considered to be array of bytes

in BitSet each component of the bit set has a boolean value

> Every bit set has a current size,
>   which is the number of bits of space
>   currently in use by the bit set. Note
>   that the size is related to the
>   implementation of a bit set, so it may
>   change with implementation. The length
>   of a bit set relates to logical length
>   of a bit set and is defined
>   independently of implementation.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to my question seeing how I already know what a BitSet is

Comment: BitSet does not use booleans. It uses longs.

Comment: just i want to clarify with a reason that you can't  create a BitSet of size 8 and store it as a byte. you may try what @WhiteFang34 mentions

Answer (score -1):

The BitSet class is obviously not intended to export or import its bits to native datatypes and also quite heavy if you just want to deal with the fixed size of a single byte. It might thus not be what you need if you just want to manipulate the bits of a byte independently and then use the resulting byte. It seems you might just want to use a API like this:

```
SimpleBitSet bs = new SimpleBitSet( 'A' );
bs.setBit( 5 );
byte mybyte = bs.getByte();
```

So a implementation of such a simplified bit set could look like this:

```
public class SimpleBitSet
{
    private byte bits;

    public SimpleBitSet( int bits )
    {
        this.bits = (byte) bits;
    }

    public byte getByte()
    {
        return bits;
    }

    public boolean getBit( int idx )
    {
        checkIndex( idx );
        return ( bits & ( 1 << idx ) ) != 0;
    }

    public void setBit( int idx )
    {
        checkIndex( idx );
        bits |= 1 << idx;
    }

    public void clearBit( int idx )
    {
        checkIndex( idx );
        bits &= ~( 1 << idx );
    }

    protected void checkIndex( int idx )
    {
        if( idx < 0 || idx > 7 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "index: " + idx );
    }    
}
```